# Link external JS file with FreeMarker template

Tags: javascript, freemarker

I want to link an external java script file with my FreeMarker template 
I used the normal    `<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"/>` but it didn't work , it works only when I use include which is not what I want .
I want to use the js file as external one.

Answer (score 2):

your js file needs to be available to the public. 
Static files in struts could be placed inside a static folder inside your jar file and can then be accessed via the url /static/path/to/your/file

see: https://struts.apache.org/docs/static-content.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an external file, you have to use a link such as `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://url/to/your/file/test.js'` and then again, you can always put the script inside some `<script>` tags. *Ex:* `<script>console.log("This is my Script!")</script>`

Comment: by external I mean a file on the filesystem besides the ftl file , but as I said it doesn't work , say I'll only put alert('test'); inside the js file and make the scipt src="" tag in the head , nothing is alerted

Comment: @emadomara If your JS file is in the same directory as your HTML file, then you would simply type the name of the file. If it's in a different directory, you would need to put the file path I believe.

Comment: Thx , I created a dummy web project and this is ok , but using strtus2 with freemarker templates it doesn't work , and the strange thing is that I can save the page ctr+Save and run it offline and the java script works :D I think there is a problem in struts2 or freemarker that disables the use of external js files

Comment: yes it works with me when I put them (js,css) under the web application not in external folder outside the app .